# C:Why does a seemingly right algorithm goes wrong as input gets big?

Tags: c

The original question is:
Define a function that produces the n'th Fibonacci number, according to the defeintion:
   fib(0)=1;fib(1)=1;fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

I was trying to solve this with if & else structure in C programming . I did it successfully and tested it with some small inputs. When the input number is '45', everything seems alright. However when input '46', the result became negative which indicates something must have gone wrong. 
   Really hope that someone can tell me why's that, and what was I doing wrong?

[The result when input 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90d0B.png)

[the result when input 46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzGz7.png)

Source Code:

## include

```
int fib(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
     return 1;
    else if (i == 1)
      {
        int result_1 = fib(i - 1);
        return result_1;
    }
    else 
    {
        int result_2= fib(i-1) + fib(i-2);
        return result_2;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("The final result is %d\n", fib(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is beyond `INT_MAX` which is probably `+2147483647`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So are there any methods by which I can get the right answer (when input number is beyond 45) ?

Comment: You need to extend the variable by using `long long int` instead of `int` but this requires **C99 std.**

Comment: C doesn't check if you are outside of the range of a specific data-type. On your machine the first bit indicates if it's a negative number. Normally half of the numbers are negative, and the other half is positive.  Fibonacci series converge exponentially.
You could use long as an example, but you will run into the same problem very fast. you can test this out easily by having a int which has the max postive integer value assigned and then add 1 to it. you will see that you're suddenly in the ngative range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to `int` is signed and becomes negative after `2e16 - 1`.

Try using `unsigned int`. But even if this works, you are still limited but `int` maximum size.

You can try using `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` or `double` to check how far you can get with your function.

Comment: I will rephrase this: _But even if this works, you are still limited but int maximum size._ to:  But even if this works, you are still in the range of `[UINT_MIN ... UINT_MAX]`